# Where to add code CSV to Model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a large CSV file that I want to populate a model that will not change once the columns are populated with CSV. I also have the method that I believe will take the CSV and add it to the database model. I am not sure where to put the method and how to call it?

Currently I have the method in a .rb file within my rails app and I'm calling it from the terminal. But I'm getting the following error:

```
ruby postcode.rb
postcode.rb:6:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Place (NameError)
    from postcode.rb:5:in `each'
    from postcode.rb:5:in `<main>'
Method / .rb file:
```

Here is my method for parsing the CSV and adding each array within the array to the 'Place' model.

```
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read('GB_full.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
Place.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

Model:

```
class CreatePlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.string :country_code
      t.string :postal_code
      t.string :place_name
      t.string :admin_name_1
      t.string :admin_code_1
      t.string :admin_name_2
      t.string :admin_code_2
      t.string :admin_name_3
      t.string :admin_code_3
      t.string :latitude
      t.string :longitude
      t.string :accuracy

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put this in a migration.  If you think you are likely to want to do it again at some point, then put the bulk of the code in the model as a class method (which takes a csv filename), and then call it from a migration.

Comment: Thanks @MaxWilliams but I'm not sure how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to the `Place` model firstly, and you can refactor it out after, when/if your model gets bloated

```
require 'csv'

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import_from_csv(text)
    CSV.parse(text, :headers => false).each do |row|
      create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

and call it like this:

```
csv_text = File.read('GB_full.csv')
Place.import_from_csv(csv_text)
```

Comment: Do I just run that from the rails console?

Comment: Yes, if your file is in the rails root folder. If not just specify the full path of the file. And you need to add the above method to your model